# Vlookup on multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have really simple task, but I'm facing some issues. 
I have three columns, first is for products ( C3 ), second is for serial number ( D3 ) and the 3th is "resultants".

"resultants" are cell in second sheet, some "resultants" are based only on product number and we have some "resultants" based on combination from products and serial number.

I was thinking that if I use non "True Match" will work in formula like :

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(C3;D3);'Sheet'!A:B;2;1);"")
```

But unfortunately is not working how it should be.
We want to see resultants based on true match, but how I said sometimes is only product ( all serials are included ) and some times is specific product and serial number.

I think index + match is not a good option because that rows from the 2nd sheet are dynamic ( there is always adding and removing products ).

All ideas will be appreciated.

Here is example on this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/u2nyv0yikzhdp6ralszys/example.xls?dl=0&rlkey=gjoz4yngtfel53ftrwljwx56r)

Comment: (1) If you can't determine one set of criteria for your lookup then you must try first one way and, if that fails, the other within one formula. (2) VLookup can only handle one look-up value. If you must look for more you can't use VLookup. (3) Your task is complex and your description totally insufficient. Post some pictures of your data.

Comment: If you concatenate look-up values together then vlookup can do 2 or 3 at a time using a helper column...

Comment: @Variatus : I update the post and provide a small example of the file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The serial number is irrelevant. Just match the product number with an "*" before or after that (depends on how you combine product number and serial number in your m&b list). Example: if your m&b range is [product number][serial number], then use the following:

```
=index([resultant range], match(C3 & "*", [m&b range],0))
```